# AWS S3 Static Website via Nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a static website on AWS S3 via the AWS node SDK.  I am at the step where I am [putting the bucket website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketWebsite-property).  I am calling `putBucketWebsite(params = {}, callback)` with the following parameters:

```
{
  "Bucket": "xxx.example.com",
  "WebsiteConfiguration": {
    "IndexDocument": {
      "Suffix": "index.html"
    },
    "RoutingRules": []
  }
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

`MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema`

What am I doing wrong?

When I `getBucketWebsite` from a site that works, I get:

```
{
  "IndexDocument": {
    "Suffix": "index.html"
  },
  "RoutingRules": []
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to not include `RoutingRules` at all?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin yes.  That causes a different error.

Comment: Which one? Because as it seems in the doc, if you specify RoutingRules key, you need to specify objects inside it

Comment: Actually, that did work.  I could have sworn that I tried that....  Thanks!  Submit an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `RoutingRules` from your request. As per [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketWebsite-property) it requires some properties to be present.